# How to access the property of the constructor?

Tags: javascript, object

How can I access the `color` property of the constructor, from the `setColor` function?

```
function Obj() {
  this.color = undefined;
}

Obj.prototype.setColor = () => {
  for (var k = 0, hex = "0123456789ABCDEF", max = hex.length, random, color = ""; k < 6;
    ++k, random = Math.floor(Math.random() * max), color += hex[random]);
  this.color = "#" + color; // Here i need to change
};

var ball = new Obj();
ball.setColor();
console.log(ball.color);
```

So, I want to run the `setColor` function and change the `color` property of `Obj` the constructor.

What is the most elegant and simple method, without declare a var to the context and use that?

Comment: `this.color = …`

Comment: this is other context

Comment: what? this.color should work...

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I lacked information, now you can try my new snippet and see why I said, that "this.color" fails

Comment: It fails because you are now using an arrow function. Don't use an arrow function.

Comment: why dont use arrow function, Felix Kling

Comment: @carloscerdadiaz Because arrow functions cannot be used as methods, lacking dynamic `this`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor doesn't have a `color` property.

The constructor function adds a `color` property **to the instance** as it is constructing it.

You can access the property on the instance with `this.color` (inside the function on the prototype).

```js
function Obj() {
  this.color = "";
}

Obj.prototype.setColor = function() {
  for (var k = 0, hex = "0123456789ABCDEF", max = hex.length, random, color = ""; k < 6;
    ++k, random = Math.floor(Math.random() * max), color += hex[random]);
  this.color = "#" + color;
};

var instance = new Obj();
instance.setColor();
console.log(instance.color);
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I lacked information, now you can try my new snippet and see why I said, that "this.color" fails

Comment: @carloscerdadiaz — Before you edited the code, you were using a function expression. Now you are using an arrow function, so `this` works differently. Don't use an arrow function.

Comment: Why dont use arrow function ? you can explain me , please ?

Comment: @carloscerdadiaz — Because `this` works differently in arrow functions.